# Adding/removing history state on single page web app

Tags: javascript, web-deployment, single-page-application

I have a single page web application (consisting of A,B,C views) which is appended inside a website. The requirement is when user is in B view of the single web page app they should be able to copy the URL and when we open that URL in another screen the single page web app should set B view. 
To do that I appended an ID to the url using window.pushstate on B view and I need to remove that state on A and C views.

First, I am not sure this is the correct or best practice approach. I 'd like to know your advice on how would you do it.

Second, how to remove the state on A and C views?

Third, I don't know when and how to call window.popstate on single page app to set the B view if the ID exist on the url.

Comment: Using which framework? Because that's essential information; each one has different best practices. And if you're not using a framework, this is not a question for Stackoverflow yet, pick one of several popular, well-documented ones and read through its tutorial(s), then roll with that.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript%20single%20page%20application%20router

Answer (score 1):

Before I start I presume your route structure looks like this:

```
xyz.com/:id
```

When the page loads, parse the url and get the id. Based on the id, render the appropriate template and append it to the page.

Also, would be extremely helpful if you use a library to manage the state.
I use this one:

```
https://visionmedia.github.io/page.js/
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If I use page.js do I still need to use window.history and push the state ?

Comment: No you don't. pagejs does that for you.